# How should I store the user's data after login for fast access during the session, after retrieving from database?

Tags: php, database, oop, session

I am developing a social network from scratch and need to store the
user's frequently required data like his friendlist, groups, news-feed
post Ids, so that it can be accessed fast after each refresh rather
than querying the database each time it is asked. What would be a
better way to store this data?
The application is expected to bear heavy traffic.

I was thinking of storing this data in php objects after the user
login. I am using PHP OOPs model to interact with the database thus my
data is retrieved though objects & retrieved data is stored in objects
after query from database. So, Instead of destroying the object as
soon as its value has been passed once, I would retain the required
objects uptil the user is logged in.
Is this the correct way?

I am just a newbie..

Thanks..

Comment: What's wrong with querying database?

Comment: Also, I have question which I cannot resist to ask. How do you think, is it possible for a newbie to create a real high-traffic site?

Comment: through learning from examples, and from others & practicing, I think. Do you think it is almost impossible or extremely difficult? Would be great if you can suggest any resources which would be useful for my case..Thanks for asking.

Comment: Regarding querying database each time, I think it would be quite expensive if on each page refresh/change, I query the friend-list then query the feeds from friends, since user's network is required for deciding & fetching almost all content, I think it's wiser to store it in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing in a session... the whole data stored in session is loaded at script status. To sum it up:

1. Only the original session owner will be able to access data
2. All session data is loaded before the script initialized. It'll be loaded every time user will change a page or issue AJAX call. I think not really "fast" thing.

Develop yourself simple caching class:

- **$cache** = new xcache($obj_name, $expire);
- **get()** -> gets object value -> false if not-found / expired
- **set($value)** -> sets object value -> (serialize it / you can do gzip compress here it's very fast)

Then use those layout to write caching mechanism using: memcache / myisam table / apc / mongodb, etc. On everything beside files you can implement an ACID cache. The important thing is not choosing what you'll use now, but implement something that'll allow you to easily change it later :)

I don't know if you need groups within your cache... if you do it'll limit the technologies you can use (eg. to clean all caching data for specific user after updating one of his DB tables). Another good thing is to assign table name to each cache item, everything could be updated very easy then.

Answer (score 0):

I would store this kind of data in the session, as objects (a User object with name, list of friends etc... properties). But I'm not sure about it's a good idea to store all this data because of (at least) 2 reasons :

1. If you have many logged in users, all these objects stored in the sessions add up and can fill your memory quite fast
2. Things like friends lists, groups etc. will evolve during the user's session so if you just load them at log-in and don't update them later they will be out of date (e.g. if the user adds a friend during his session)

A better solution would be a general persistence cache, so that objects that have been loaded once from the DB are not reloaded every time thex are needed. Such mechanisms exist in persistence frameworks such as Hibernate (Java/.Net) I don't know about PHP.